# Relative/Absolute positioning inside container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position some divs inside another container,
When I set `position: relative;` on those divs they are drawn inside the container but when I add the `top` and `left` style properties, they aren't drawn correctly

here is my code:

```
<table style="background:black;width:80%;height:90%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="background:yellow;width:15%">Left Pane</td>
        <td style="background:black;width:85%">
            <div id="a" style="background:green;position:relative;top:1px;left:80px;width:20%;height:20%">a</div>
            <div id="b" style="background:blue;position:relative;top:10px;left:14px;width:20%;height:20%">b</div>
            <div id="c" style="background:red;position:relative;top:10px;left:14px;width:20%;height:20%">c</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

as you can see divs `#b` & `#c` should be placed on each other because of their `top` & `left` properties but they are drawn beneath each other,
If I set `position: absolute;` they are placed on each other, but they aren't positioned according to their container but according to the screen.

Is there any way to position the divs on top of each other according to their container?

Comment: try setting: position:relative on td, and position:absolute on a & b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn about position relative and absolute:

[css tricks: position relative and absolute](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

in short:

the container elements gets `position: relative;`

the elements inside it, get `position: absolute;` and values for `top/bottom/left/right`

this allows you to control positioning and it is cross-browser compatible (old versions of IE handle positioning in a terrible way!)

PS a couple of generic suggestions to improve your coding skills:

- try to avoid using tables for layout.
- use an external css file rather than inline - it's easier to mantain on the long run and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative` for the container and `position: absolute` for the inner elements.

```
<td style="position: relative">
  <div id="a" style="position: absolute; top:1px;left:80px;width:20%;height:20%">a</div>
  <div id="b" style="position: absolute; top:10px;left:14px;width:20%;height:20%">b</div>
  <div id="c" style="position: absolute; top:10px;left:14px;width:20%;height:20%">c</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relatively positioned parent and absolutely position the divs: see my js fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/VeL3c/

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">Left Pane</td>
        <td class="right">
            <div id="a">a</div>
            <div id="b">b</div>
            <div id="c">c</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>​
```

CSS

```
table {
    background:black; width:80%; height:90%;
}

td.left {
    background:yellow; width:15%;
}

td.right {
    position: relative; background:black; width:85%
}

#a, #b, #c {
    position:absolute; top:0px;
}

#a {
    background:green;left:80px; width:20%;
}

#b, #c {
    left:14px;width:20%;
    background: blue;
}

#c {
    background:red;
}
```